# Javascript access object properties under same hierarchy

Tags: javascript, object

Hi i am newb to javascript when i was trying write a code i encounter this problem

```js
var k = { 
  
    sam: {
      b: k.bar.x,
      },
  
    bar: {
      x: "Hi",
     },
  };
```

I dono how to access that bar.x property. I tried using getter and setters.

I know it can be accessed if i use **b:this.k.bar.x** . But this bad way to access it.

Please clarify my doubt. Is my understanding is wrong or my code is wrong.
Thank you

Comment: You can't use object properties that way. Create the object with all constant fields and then add dynamic ones *afterwards*.

Comment: No, it cannot be accessed using `b: this.k.bar.x`.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will help, taken straight from the MDN website.

```
var myHonda = {color: "red", wheels: 4, engine: {cylinders: 4, size: 2.2}};
```

[MDN Objects ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

I can't post pictures yet, but after writing that javascript, I opened my console and typed: `myHonda.engine.cylinders` and it returned 4. So that is how it works, to clarify.